# converting kilometers to mph in python

Tags: python

just a quick question on this code that I am trying to understand.

for the last line of this code I don't understand why there is a 0.3f in the print statement. The "%" makes sense because the variable kilometers and miles is being inserted inside the statement but, the 0.3f has me kind of lost.

```
# Program to convert kilometers into miles 
# Input is provided by the user in kilometers

# take input from the user
kilometers = float(input('How many kilometers?: '))

# conversion factor
conv_fac = 0.621371

# calculate miles
miles = kilometers * conv_fac
print('%0.3f kilometers is equal to %0.3f miles' %(kilometers,miles))
```

Comment: 3 decimals after the comma

Comment: @h3n after the dot :)

Comment: Look up "fixed point" in string-formatting: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 2):

`.3` defines the precision. this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6)